# I want to practice testing API but can't find anything interesting

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, api, api-automation

I want to practice in automating API testing but can't find anything interesting. Everything that I found were on the one hand rather complicated, on the other hand they did not allow testing such methods as POST, PUT and DELETE.
Can anybody suggest me some open API which is already online to use as a playground?

Comment: Try this https://www.zippopotam.us/

Answer (score 3):

Try the petstore - it's a common API used in examples. I used it when working with JMeter and it's a useful API to practice with.

https://petstore3.swagger.io/

You can do all sorts of different things there.

Answer (score 2):

[Restful-Booker](https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/) is purpose made for learning to test an API. You can either use the online version, or you can check out the [repo](https://github.com/mwinteringham/restful-booker) and run it locally if you prefer.

I think it's a pretty useful site to practice with, and it does seem to be actively maintained - the author has written a couple of courses on API testing which are pretty useful (linked from the first page above).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/TonnyL/Awesome_APIs) and [this](https://github.com/egfx/Awesome-APIs) GitHub repositories provide a curated list of service projects, many open source, and buildable by running a couple of Docker commands.

You may also want to visit [this site.](https://apilist.fun/)

As an example of a simple API from a "real site" is Trello.
I've written [a blog post](http://thatsabug.com/blog/intro_postman_trello/) showing a CRUD cycle in it for Postman. Nonetheless, it's direct to transcribe the flow to any other automation in testing tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

### Postman

If you install and use Postman ( a leading API tool with a free version) there is training and examples on their site and within the tool.  As postman is a leading tool this is a good one to learn

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for RestAPI manual and automation testing you can go with

**Advance Rest Client** :- for manual testing & very easy to use

**Rest Assured** :- Rest-API Automation quite easy to use if you have java knowledge also easy to integrate with testng and junit .

Answer (score 0):

i usually use Postman for API testing , it helps you and you'll find so documentation and training examples
-Jmeter, is more usefull for stress testing / performance testing (i think !)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [rest-assured tests](https://github.com/ProgrammerOfTheMillennium/rest-assured/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/AppTest.java) with a docker json rest server. You can use it and practice any of HTTP requests. Stack: Java, RestAssured, TestNG, Maven

Links:

- [repo main page](https://github.com/ProgrammerOfTheMillennium/rest-assured)
- [readme of the docker server](https://github.com/ProgrammerOfTheMillennium/rest-assured/tree/master/docker-json-server)
- [exaples of rest tests](https://github.com/ProgrammerOfTheMillennium/rest-assured/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/AppTest.java)